# What is the correct behaviour for date.setHours(-1)?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have the following code:

```
var date = new Date(2010,09,09); //09.10.2010 00:00
date.setHours(-1); //sets the date to 08.10.2010 23:00
```

Calling `date.setHours(-1);` sets the date to 23:00 at the previous day (at least for Opera and Chrome).

Is this legal?

Comment: What do you mean with "Is this legal"?

Comment: Which is exactly like suspected. If I am at day 2, 0:00 hours an hour ago it was day 1 23:00. So yeah, to me this seems perfectly legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is effectively what the specification dictates, so it would be an "illegal" implementation if it didn't.

The actual computation happens in [`MakeDate`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.13). The date is converted into milliseconds, as is the -1 hours. These are then added. Adding a negative number does subtraction, so you get an earlier date.

> If `day` is not finite or `time` is not finite, return `NaN`.
>
> Return `day` × `msPerDay` + `time`.

Answer (score 6):

Not only is it legal, is it *required*.

The behaviour is officially defined in the [ECMAScript specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.34), section 15.9.5.34:

> **Date.prototype.setHours (hour [, min [, sec [, ms ] ] ] )**
>
> If *min* is not specified, this behaves as if *min* were specified with the value **`getMinutes()`**.
>
> If *sec* is not specified, this behaves as if *sec* were specified with the value **`getSeconds()`**.
>
> If *ms* is not specified, this behaves as if *ms* were specified with the value **`getMilliseconds()`**.
>
> 1. Let *t* be the result of LocalTime(this time value).
> 2. Let *h* be ToNumber(*hour*).
> 3. If *min* is not specified, then let *m* be MinFromTime(*t*); otherwise, let *m* be ToNumber(*min*).
> 4. If *sec* is not specified, then let *s* be SecFromTime(*t*); otherwise, let *s* be ToNumber(*sec*).
> 5. If *ms* is not specified, then let *milli* be msFromTime(*t*); otherwise, let *milli* be ToNumber(*ms*).
> 6. Let *date* be MakeDate(Day(*t*), MakeTime(*h*, *m*, *s*, *milli*)).
> 7. Let *u* be TimeClip(UTC(*date*)).
> 8. Set the [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of this Date object to *u*.
> 9. Return *u*

And the specification for `MakeTime`, used in step 6, ultimately calculates a millisecond offset by multiplying the various parts together.  There are no preconditions for bounds on the arguments (other than that they are finite), so a negative number of hours is legal, and will result in a negative result.

Thus the overall result, that is midnight + (-1 hours), does need to be 23:00 on the previous day to conform with the spec.

Answer (score 2):

Ask a lawyer for legality. But you may want to do:

`date.setHours(date.getHours()-1);`

to get it right - as in, what you expected.

Maybe worth to remark that `setDate(-1)`, `setMonth(-1)` and `setYear(-1)` *don't* work the way you expect.

Comment: I expected 23:00, but I was worried some browsers will do something else, i.e. throw an exception.

Comment: Well, *even* IE7 gets it right (also with `getHours(-1)`, so my suggestion may be superfluous